# How to count different columns in SQL ignoring the column order

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have a table like this:

```
home_city     away_city
-----------------------

Valencia      Madrid        
Barcelona     Madrid
Madrid        Valencia
Alicante      Castellon
Madrid        Valencia
Castellon     Alicante
Valencia      Madrid
```

I want to count the rows for each one of the distinct combinations, but **ignoring if it's a *home_city* or an *away_city*.** 
I mean, usually I would do a Query like that

```
SELECT home_city, away_city, COUNT(*) as count_cities
FROM my_table
GROUP BY home_city, away_city
```

and it would return the following result:

```
home_city     away_city     count_cities
----------------------------------------

Valencia      Madrid        2
Barcelona     Madrid        1        
Madrid        Valencia      2
Alicante      Castellon     1
Castellon     Alicante      1
```

But what I really want is the query ignore the column and return me something like that:

```
home_city     away_city     count_cities
----------------------------------------

Valencia      Madrid        4
Barcelona     Madrid        1        
Alicante      Castellon     2
```

It doesn't matter if the result is returned in one column or two columns.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Switch columns of home_city > away_city, before the group by.

Comment: It doesn't back sense to have home_city and away_city as headers in the required result set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `least()` and `greatest()`:

```
SELECT LEAST(home_city, away_city) as city1,
       GREATEST(home_city, away_city) as city2,
       COUNT(*) as count_cities
FROM my_table
GROUP BY LEAST(home_city, away_city),
         GREATEST(home_city, away_city);
```

MySQL allows aliases in the `GROUP BY`, so you can simplify this to:

```
SELECT LEAST(home_city, away_city) as city1,
       GREATEST(home_city, away_city) as city2,
       COUNT(*) as count_cities
FROM my_table
GROUP BY city1, city2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my lame version, but no advanced SQL knowledge needed ;)

```
SELECT CASE WHEN home_city < away_city THEN CONCAT(home_city, ',', away_city) ELSE CONCAT(away_city, ',', home_city) END as cities, COUNT(*) as count
FROM X2
GROUP BY CASE WHEN home_city < away_city THEN CONCAT(home_city, ',', away_city) ELSE CONCAT(away_city, ',', home_city) END;
```

```
--drop table X2;
create table X2 
(home_city varchar(255), away_city varchar(255));


insert into X2 values ('Valencia','Madrid');        
insert into X2 values ('Barcelona','Madrid');
insert into X2 values ('Madrid','Valencia');
insert into X2 values ('Alicante','Castellon');
insert into X2 values ('Madrid','Valencia');
insert into X2 values ('Castellon','Alicante');
insert into X2 values ('Valencia','Madrid');

SELECT CASE WHEN home_city < away_city THEN CONCAT(home_city, ',', away_city) ELSE CONCAT(away_city, ',', home_city) END as cities, COUNT(*) as count
FROM X2
GROUP BY CASE WHEN home_city < away_city THEN CONCAT(home_city, ',', away_city) ELSE CONCAT(away_city, ',', home_city) END;
```

```
cities  count
Alicante,Castellon  2
Barcelona,Madrid    1
Madrid,Valencia 4
```

Comment: The other solution seems simpler